# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a sign up page for my app.

```
Future<int> attemptSignup (String name, String username, String password) async {
    var res = await http.post(
      'http://ec2-13-233-140-222.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/Users',
       body: {
        "user" : {
          "UserName":username,
          "password":password,
          "Name": name,
        }
       }
    );
    return res.statusCode;
  }
```

and using this here so that people can create an account:

```
onTap: () async {

      var username = _usernameController.text;
      var password = _passwordController.text;
      var name = _nameController.text;

      if( username.length < 4)
        displayDialog(context, "Invalid Username", "Username should be atleast 4 characters long");
      else if (password.length < 4)
        displayDialog(context, "Invalid password", "The password should be atleast 4 characters long");
      else {
        var res = await attemptSignup(name, username, password);
        if (res ==200)
          displayDialog(context, "Success", "The user was created. Go back and Log in now");
        else if (res ==409)
          displayDialog(context, "This Email is already registered", "Please login, or create an account with different Email");
        else{
          displayDialog(context, "Error", "An unknown error occurred");
          print(res);
        }
      }
    },
```

When I try to run the app, it runs normally. But when I fill in the details and try to create an account it doesn't really give an error- it just doesn't go through. After reading the console following lines come up:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

I tried researching on stackoverflow and github, this error InternalLinkedHasMap pops up while networking with apis. But I couldn't find an instance that was solving my issue.

Comment: `_InternalLinkedHashMap` is the name of the class that's instantiated when you use `Map`.  The error means that you're using a `Map` where a `String` is expected somewhere (a stack trace probably would guide you to where).

Comment: I checked, but I am not using ```Map``` anywhere near this program.

Comment: The above two pieces of code is all there is to sign up, nothing more. I even deleted other files where I may have used map, but this error persists

Comment: "I am not using `Map` anywhere near this program." The code you showed in this post shows two of them!  Looking at the documentation for [`http.post`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html), `body` may be a "`String`, a `List<int>`, or a `Map<String, String>`".  You are passing a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, which is the wrong type.  You will need to encode the nested `Map` to a `String` yourself first.

Comment: My error sir, I'm super new- and I didn't understand ```Map```.  Backend post req required this body so I just pasted. I'll read up the following resources. It would be a big help if you could also point out on how to encode the nested ```Map``` to string. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm a little late. Well, in case someone needs it.

```
 body: {
        "user" : "{
          "UserName":username,
          "password":password,
          "Name": name,
        }"
       }
    );
```